# How to compare nullable types?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, nullable

I have a few places where I need to compare 2 (nullable) values, to see if they're the same.

I think there should be something in the framework to support this, but can't find anything, so instead have the following:

```
public static bool IsDifferentTo(this bool? x, bool? y)
{
    return (x.HasValue != y.HasValue) ? true : x.HasValue && x.Value != y.Value;
}
```

Then, within code I have `if (x.IsDifferentTo(y)) ...`

I then have similar methods for nullable ints, nullable doubles etc.

Is there not an easier way to see if two nullable types are the same?

**Update:**

Turns out that the reason this method existed was because the code has been converted from VB.Net, where Nothing = Nothing returns false (compare to C# where null == null returns true). The VB.Net code should have used `.Equals...` instead.

Comment: bit late on this but I found the update useful. ran into the same scenario

Answer (score 92, accepted):

C# supports "lifted" operators, so if the type (`bool?` in this case) is known at compile you should just be able to use:

```
return x != y;
```

If you need generics, then `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` is your friend:

```
return !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x,y);
```

Note, however, that both of these approaches use the "`null == null`" approach (contrast to ANSI SQL). If you need "`null != null`"  then you'll have to test that separately:

```
return x == null || x != y;
```

Answer (score 49):

You can use [`Nullable.Equals<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.equals).

Comment: Other answers are claiming that `x.Equals(y)` and `x == y` work just fine when x and/or y are instances of `Nullable<T>`. How is the linked method different? When should it be used?

Comment: Or `Nullabe.Compare<T>` if you are looking for an `IComparable<T>` impl

Answer (score 32):

You can just use the [Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.equals) method of `Nullable<T>`:

```
bool areDifferent = x.Equals(y);
```

## Your method is redundant

Your method is then simplified to:

```
public static bool IsDifferentTo(this bool? x, bool? y) => !x.Equals(y);
```

Which is redundant to just calling equals:

- `one.IsDifferentTo(other)` is the same as `!one.Equals(other)`.
- `IsDifferentTo(one, other)` is the same as `!Nullable.Equals(one,other)`.

## Safety from NullReferenceExceptions

This will not throw a NullReferenceException because a `int?`, synonym of `Nullable<int>`, is a struct — a value type, not a reference type.
You can test this quickly:

```
Nullable<int> test = null;
// result is false; no NullReferenceException is thrown.
bool isNull = test.HasValue;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why this downvote. Just wanted to know where I am wrong.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but what happens if x is null? Invoking a method on a null reference would probably result in a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Chris: You should upvote the answer again. A nullable type `T?` is NOT a reference type, it's a `System.Nullable<T>`. And this is a struct, so: a value type. Muhammad's code is perfectly legal and won't throw a NullReferenceException if x is null.

Comment: @Chris: Oh, sorry, sorry, I misread that you did NOT downvote the answer, so you are free to upvote or not ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the static [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) method on System.Object:

```
var equal = object.Equals(objA, objB);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Compare:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxxt7t2a.aspx

Comment: You don't need compare to check for equality; this is only needed for real comparison such as for sorting.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `==`, or `.Equals()`.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to find how to compare two nullable int on C#, but I always get this link after search, so if someone needs to compare exactly two nullable int, then this can be helpful

`a.GetValueOrDefault(int.MinValue).CompareTo(b.GetValueOrDefault(long.MinValue));`

Answer (score 0):

```
(x?? 0).Equals(y)
```

will handle null as well as equals.

Comment: This is wrong. Can you correct or remove the answer? Because: 1. If `x=null;` and `y=0;` , they are not equal but this code says that they are; and 2. equality [**must** be symmetric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type), but this code says that null is _equal_ to 0 while 0 is _not equal_ to null.